# Как обновлять прогноз погоды онлайн?

Tags: javascript, html, css, openweathermap

Коллеги, у меня есть полуготовый код на js. Мне нужно, что б определялся город в классе `weather__city` и для этого города автоматически обновлялась, температура воды  `<p class="weather__temperature">+23<sup>o</sup>C - воздух</p>` (если это возможно), дата `<p class="weather__date">29.05.2020</p>`, и температура воздуха `<p class="weather__temperature">+23<sup>o</sup>C - воздух</p>` вместе с иконкой `<div class="weather__icon"><i class="fas fa-sun"></i></div>`.

Всё выше описанное является моей проблемой и прошу у Вас помощи! Ниже прилагаю код.
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

```js
const api = {
 key: "11c85ec89d2ab590110511a07349dd25",
 baseurl: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
}

const weather__wrapper = document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setQuery);
var boolean = false;

function setQuery(evt) {
 boolean = true;
 getResults(boolean);
}


function getResults (query) {
 fetch(`${api.baseurl}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
 .then(weather=> {
  return weather.json();
 }).then(displayResults);
}


function displayResults(weather) {
 console.log(weather);
 let city = document.querySelector('.weather__text .weather__city');
 city.innerText = `${weather.name}, ${weather.sys.counry}`;

 let now = new Date();
 let date = document.querySelector('.weather__text .weather__date');
 date.innerText = dateBuilder(now);
}

function dateBuilder(d) {
 let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
 let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

 let day = days[d.getDay()];
 let date = d.getDate();
 let month = months[d.getMonth()];
 let year = d.getFullYear();

 return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
}
```

```css
.weather__wrapper {
 height: 186px;
 width: 355px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #e4e8ef;
 padding: 24px 24px 24px 24px;


 margin-left: 30px; /* убрать */
}

.weather__icon {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 26px;
}

.weather__icon i {
 color: #fab165;
 font-size: 5.938em;
}

.weather__text {
 float: right;
}

.weather__city  { /* Локация, на видел input */
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.500em;
 margin-bottom: 0!important;
}

.weather__temperature {
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 1.500em;
 margin-bottom: 0!important;
}

.weather__date {
 font-size: 1.250em;
 font-weight: 200;
 margin-bottom: 0!important;
}

.slide-weather__items {
 display: flex;
 outline: none;
}

.slide-weather {
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="slide-weather">
        Hello
        <div class="slide-weather__items">
            <div class="weather__wrapper">
                <!-- weather on video -->
                <div class="weather__icon"><i class="fas fa-sun"></i></div>
                <div class="weather__text">
                    <p class="weather__city">г. Сочи</p>
                    <div class="weather__current-temp">
                        <p class="weather__temperature">+23<sup>o</sup>C - воздух</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="weather__water">
                        <p class="weather__temperature">+23<sup>o</sup>C - вода</p>    
                    </div>
                    <p class="weather__date">29.05.2020</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="weather__wrapper">
                <!-- weather on video -->
                <div class="weather__icon"><i class="fas fa-sun"></i></div>
                <div class="weather__text">
                    <p class="weather__city">г. Новороссийск</p>
                    <div class="weather__current-temp">
                        <p class="weather__temperature">+23<sup>o</sup>C - воздух</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="weather__water">
                        <p class="weather__temperature">+23<sup>o</sup>C - вода</p>    
                    </div>
                    <p class="weather__date">29.05.2020</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="weather__wrapper">
                <!-- weather on video -->
                <div class="weather__icon"><i class="fas fa-sun"></i></div>
                <div class="weather__text">
                    <p class="weather__city">г. Геленджик</p>
                    <div class="weather__current-temp">
                        <p class="weather__temperature">+23<sup>o</sup>C - воздух</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="weather__water">
                        <p class="weather__temperature">+23<sup>o</sup>C - вода</p>    
                    </div>
                    <p class="weather__date">29.05.2020</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/weather.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```